# Mysql Multiple statements different conditions

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql table:

```
CREATE TABLE `templates_assignments` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `type` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '2' 
  `assignment_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `template_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `template_id` (`template_id`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=122 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

/*Data for the table `templates_assignments` */

insert  into `templates_assignments`
(`id`,`type`,`assignment_id`,`template_id`)
values 
  (15,1,1,1),
  (16,1,1,2),
  (19,1,1,6),
  (54,2,30,6),
  (55,1,5,11),
  (56,1,5,15),
  (57,1,5,22);
```

I want to select the template that qualifies for both conditions:

1. type=2 AND assignment_id=30
2. type=1 AND assignment_id=1

the only template_id that should come back is 6, but i keep getting all or none.

My query condition was something like:

```
WHERE 
(
    (templatesAssignments.type=2 AND templatesAssignments.assignment_id=30) AND (templatesAssignments.type=1 AND templatesAssignments.assignment_id=1)
)
```

But no luck...what am i missing?

Comment: `(templatesAssignments.type=2 AND templatesAssignments.assignment_id=30) OR (templatesAssignments.type=1 AND templatesAssignments.assignment_id=1)` but only if they are not exclusives

Comment: tried it....no luck i get back all templates

Comment: You have to join the table to itself using aliases.

Comment: @HannoBinder not sure what it means....i'm not too mysql saavy :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT ta1.template_id
FROM templatesAssignments ta1
INNER JOIN templatesAssignments ta2 ON ta1.template_id = ta2.template_id
WHERE (ta1.type=1 AND ta1.assignment_id=1)
AND   (ta2.type=2 AND ta2.assignment_id=30)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
select template_id
from templatesAssignments
group by template_id
having sum(type=2 AND assignment_id=30) > 0
   and sum(type=1 AND assignment_id=1) > 0
```

Comment: didnt try it but only because i needed to adjust the answer to my framework. thx anyway